# Random Password Generator Bash

Tags: bash, passwords

I am trying to make a password generator that generates a password between 8-16 characters. It also has to contain a digit and lower and uppercase letters, as well as only one special character that is randomly placed in the string when being generated.

At the moment, my code will sometimes give me a password that does not meet the requirements eg. `AOKOKKK@1` (no lowercase letters) In addition, I also need help to make it so that the special symbol only appears once in the password. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
length=$[ 8 +$[RANDOM % 16]]

char=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ! @ \# $ % ^ \&)

max=${#char[*]}
for ((i = 1; i <= $length ; i++))do

let rand=${RANDOM}%${max}
password="${password}${char[$rand]}"
done
echo $password
```

Comment: 'One special character'?  Why?  Password systems that limit the range of characters that can be used are endlessly frustrating.  They make it really hard to make really good passwords.

Comment: I agree, but im supposed to follow a guideline when it comes to creating a generator

Comment: Split the valid characters into groups: lower-case, upper-case, digits, specials.  Decide on a random sequence of the 4 groups, only including the specials once.  Or decide on a random sequence of the three main groups for 'length-1' groups; then decide on a random position for the specials within that list. Also check that each group is present at least once. Then for each character in the given length of password, generate a random specimen from the relevant group.

Comment: Do you need to do yourself as an exercise or you need a password generator? In Linux you can use pwgen (`sudo apt-get install pwgen` on debian/ubuntu)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This guarantees one and only one special characters, as well as at least one of digits, lower case, and upper case.  To place those characters randomly within the password, `sort -R` is used to scramble the order of characters before the password is printed:

```
#!/bin/bash
choose() { echo ${1:RANDOM%${#1}:1}; }

{
    choose '!@#$%^\&'
    choose '0123456789'
    choose 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    choose 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for i in $( seq 1 $(( 4 + RANDOM % 8 )) )
    do
        choose '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    done
} | sort -R | tr -d '\n'
echo ""
```

#### How it works

1. We define a convenience function:

   ```
   choose() { echo ${1:RANDOM%${#1}:1}; }
   ```

   `choose` takes one argument, a string, and randomly selects a character from that string.
2. We print one character per line of one of each of the required types of characters:

   ```
   choose '!@#$%^\&'
   choose '0123456789'
   choose 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   choose 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   ```
3. We print the remaining number of characters needed, one character per line.  These characters are selected randomly from digits, lower case, and upper case:

   ```
   for i in $( seq 1 $(( 4 + RANDOM % 8 )) )
   do
       choose '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
   done
   ```
4. From the above, the special character is always first and the digit second, etc.  We need to randomize.  We do that with `sort -R`:

   ```
   sort -R | tr -d '\n'
   ```

   `tr -d '\n'` serves to removes the newlines from between the characters, resulting in a string of characters on one line.

#### Improvement

In the comments, JonathanLeffer shows that the output of `sort -R` is not fully random.  `sort -R` sorts on a hash of each line.  Apparently a random seed is added but each line receives the same seed.  To get around this, the version below provides its own seed on each line.  This is done by a change to the `choose` function.  At the end, `awk` is used to remove those numbers and display the complete password:

```
#!/bin/bash
choose() { echo ${1:RANDOM%${#1}:1} $RANDOM; }

{
    choose '!@#$%^\&'
    choose '0123456789'
    choose 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    choose 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for i in $( seq 1 $(( 4 + RANDOM % 8 )) )
    do
        choose '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    done

} | sort -R | awk '{printf "%s",$1}'
echo ""
```

In `awk`, each line is divided into fields.  The first field is the randomly chosen letter while the second is the random number that we added to seed the hash.  The statement `printf "%s",$1` prints the first field (with no trailing whitespace) and ignores the second field.  The end result is the password that we want.

#### Capturing the password to a variable

To capture the output to a variable, we use *command substitution*:

```
choose() { echo ${1:RANDOM%${#1}:1} $RANDOM; }
pass="$({ choose '!@#$%^\&'
  choose '0123456789'
  choose 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  choose 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  for i in $( seq 1 $(( 4 + RANDOM % 8 )) )
     do
        choose '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
     done
 } | sort -R | awk '{printf "%s",$1}')"
```

Command substitution, denoted by `$(...)`, runs the commands in the parens and captures their stdout.

Comment: Neat, using a GNU sort extension with the -R option. I wonder how well single-character hashes work out for randomization? Although the man page says 'sort by random hash of keys', sorting the same data multiple times produces different orders, so there's more than just the data (key) itself used for generating the hash. So it is probably pretty reasonable. _[...time passeth...]_ If a character is repeated, the random sort seems to put all the repeats together.  See what you get with `printf "%s\n" a a a b b b c c c | sort -R`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good insight!  I tried it and I see the same thing. I modified the script to add a random number to each line before sorting and then remove the number after sorting.

Comment: Nice recovery…'twas interesting to spot that problem.  My first experiments with `-R` used all different digits, so I didn't see the problem immediately — then I got a little more thorough.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm wondering what applications there are for which the behavior you spotted would be a desired feature rather than a fault.

Comment: Good question: I'm not immediately sure.  I can see that it leaves some semblance of 'sort' in the code — it groups rows with the same key together.  It should be pretty straight-forward to create a new option (perhaps `--shuffle`) that adds an input line number to the seed and the key and generates a random permutation based on that.

Comment: A stupid question, How can I capture the output of this script in a "bash script" variable ? (I tried use your code from a custom script bash..)

Comment: @user2137454 To capture the output of any script as variable, use command substitution like `myvar="$(myscript)"`.  Also, I added to the answer an example of using command substitution to capture the output within this password script.

Answer (score 3):

[pwgen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pwgen.1.html) is installed on some linux distros (notably Ubuntu) by default and has a windows version as well. Why not use that?

Comment: The main reason seems to be that this is an exercise with rules set by someone else and the chance of `pwgen` following the desired rules is approximately nil.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Password Generator Script

echo "Password Generator Script"
read -p "Enter the password lenght: " PASS_LENGTH
for VAR in $(seq 1 3); #how many times password will generate, you can set range
do
    openssl rand -base64 48 | cut -c1-$PASS_LENGTH
    #-base64(Encode) 48 is length 
    #cut is for user input column -c1 is column1
done
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please consider explaining your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use [pwmake](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwmake) set to 128 bits to do so. It's available out of the box for most distros and makes good passwords using /dev/urandom.